# What manufacturer is this contact?

Tags: relay, automotive, pins, terminal, contact

I have a relay contact, that I am trying to identify. It is from an Audi, who mostly use TE/Tyco, but this is different. It has this marking on it:

[image: contact]

Which I have tried to replicate here for clarity:

[image: logo]

I am hoping someone might be able to identify the manufacturer so I can try and find a replacement part.

Here is a photo of the complete terminal:

[image: terminal]

Comment: Is that a standard spade connector? If so, any reputable brand (such as TE) should be fine.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the whole relay? Just showing the crimp end of an odd looking spade terminal doesn't reveal anything besides that logo.

Comment: It is not a standard spade unfortunately, as it fits into a plastic connector block. I have attached a photo of the complete part. The 'arch' part over the top is a key feature of how it is retained in the connector

Comment: If it's me working on this car, and I need to replace that terminal but can't source it,  I'm using a standard FastOn from Tyco or whoever, then applying solder to the tab.  All that extra mechanism is either to ensure better electrical contact or to prevent it from wiggling loose (or both).  Soldering the tab to the new terminal would accomplish both very well.

Comment: Can you find the manufacturer of the relay it attaches to?

Comment: @KyleB when you refer to soldering, do you mean to create your own 'tab' on the terminal so that it fits the connector securely?

Comment: @AndrewMorton unfortunately a mixture. The relay holder is not branded aside from Audi/VW (usually they are TE/Tyco branded in addition to Audi/VW). The relays are TE/Bosch etc

Comment: @MarkTickner   I mean you crimp the terminal to the wire, then push the terminal on the tab.  THEN solder such that the terminal & tab are soldered together.  At my company, which is ludicrously safety-oriented and overseen by the CPSC, we do exactly this ... Using 14 AWG wire going to an electric motor - In use w/o the solder they tend to wiggle free.   Soldering them makes 'em "permanent".   The downside, obviously, is that you would need a soldering gun to remove it.   Just measure the tab and get something that fits.   Common thickness are 0.020" and 0.032".   Widths 0.187" or 0.250"

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Audi uses TE/Tyco connectors but not always nor exclusively. You may check Bosch. The year and model will have some bearing on the connector as well. What I have is probably not good news but Audi uses custom connectors made by several terminal manufacturers as do most of the automotive manufacturers. Sometimes several use the same connector. Many are never placed on the commercial market for general public purchase. The best source is your Audi dealership. I do not know what country you are in but here is a link that may help or lead you to an answer. https://www.fcpeuro.com/Audi-parts/Electrical-Connectors/

Comment: Yes that does make sense, the connectors I usually get direct from the dealer, though the terminals I usually buy loose. The main reason being I prefer to crimp them onto my own wires compared to the precrimped short lengths Audi sell which only come in yellow and need soldering

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jimellisvwparts.com/products/Volkswagen-VW/WIRE-SET/5131548/000979144E.html

[image]

Although I couldn't source the manufacturer of the connector, this matches your part and description.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I am trying to buy the terminal separately so I can avoid buying the precrimped lengths that Audi sell, only in yellow and will then require cuttings and soldering